# Save Conflict error when editing attachment while editing its item

Tags: 2010, error, attachments

I am getting a Save Conflict error when performing the following steps -

- Open list item
- Click edit
- Open attachment
- Edit the contents of the    attachment
- Save attachment
- Save Item
- Error thrown

Does anyone know how to either stop the error from occurring?
The only workaround so far is to make sure the user updates the attachment before editing the item. However with so many users having this workaround isn't feasible.

We are using SP 2010.

Comment: Getting the same error here.
Anybody can help?

Comment: How are you editing contents of attachment ? are you doing it from local destkop software or browser based ?

Comment: Hi! Have You found the solution? >>"The only workaround so far is to make sure the user updates the attachment before editing the item" - if I edit attachment online and do not touch form I get this error anyway..